# Resize an array of class using pointer

Tags: c++

I have this segment of code in my program. I want to create an array of class `Ship` with a size that would change whenever it is going to become full. Previously I initialized `SIZE = 3` and `Ship *list = new Ship[SIZE]`. When I run it, it stops working after my array is full, which is supposed to execute the code below:

```
if(count >= SIZE)
{
    Ship *hold = new Ship[SIZE];       // to hold for a while value of list
    for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)   
        hold[q] = list[q];
    delete[] list;                     //delete list

    Ship *list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];  //set a new size for list
    for(int q = 0; q < SIZE - 10; q++)
        list[q] = hold[q];
    delete[] hold;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: `vector` is the way to go, but if you -`delete[] list;` after copying it to the new array, you only need one copy loop. eg: `Ship *hold=new Ship [SIZE];  for(int q=0;q<SIZE;q++) hold[q]=list[q]; delete[] list; list = hold;` all done.

Comment: you are first reading from something called `list`, then create a new `list` variable (which is not the `list` you've jst read from) and populate it. the the new `list` exits from scope, meaning you will never be able to use it any more.

Comment: `std::vector<Ship>` -- will solve all of these issues.  Why are you not using it?  The whole purpose of `std::vector` is to have arrays that are resizeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `hold`, just copy the old list to the new one.

But the real mistakes in your code are that you don't change `SIZE` but you assume that it has changed

```
Ship *list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];  //set a new size for list
for(int q = 0; q < SIZE - 10; q++)
```

should be

```
Ship *list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];  //set a new size for list
for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)
   ...
SIZE += 10;
```

and that you declare a new `list` variable, when you should be changing the existing `list` variable.

```
Ship *list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];  //set a new size for list
```

should be

```
list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];  //set a new size for list
```

Here's your code with all mistakes fixed

```
if(count >= SIZE)
{
    Ship *new_list = new Ship[SIZE + 10];      //make the new list
    for(int q = 0; q < SIZE; q++)              //copy from the old list
        new_list[q] = list[q];
    delete[] list;                             //delete the old list
    list = new_list;                           //use the new list
    SIZE += 10;                                //set a new size for list
}
```

Now here's the same code using `std::vector`

```
vec.resize(vec.size() + 10);
```

`std::vector` is a little bit easier (actually it's a whole lot easier). You should use it.

Comment: It worked, but just wondering, list=new_list means list would share same memory location as new_list right? is that why i do not need to delete new_list later?

Comment: For exactly that reason. Because `list` and `new_list` are pointing to the same memory (after `list = new_list`) if you deleted `new_list` then you wouldn't be able to use `list` any more.

Answer (score 0):

be careful when working with pointers.

```
// -------------- include directives:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// -------------- your class definitions
class ship {
public:
    ship() {}
    virtual ~ship() {}
};

// ------- declaration state
#define ADDITIONAL_RESERVED_SLOTS (10)
unsigned int arraySize{3};
unsigned int shipCount{}; // initial with zero count
ship* shipArray{nullptr}; // its very important to fill pointers with null for initialialization
void addNewShip(const ship& new_ship); // function prototype
```

put these lines in your initializer block of code

```
// ------- allocate array dynamicly with  3 slot
ship* shipArray = new ship[arraySize];
// zero allocated memory for pervent from mistakes
std::memset(shipArray, 0, (sizeof(ship) * arraySize));
```

add new ship in to your array with define a generic function like this:

```
void addNewShip(const ship& new_ship) {
    if(++shipCount > arraySize) {
        arraySize += ADDITIONAL_RESERVED_SLOTS;
        // allocate new array
        ship* pNewShipArray = new ship[arraySize];
        // zero allocated memory for pervent from mistakes
        std::memset(pNewShipArray, 0, (sizeof(ship) * arraySize));
        // copy previuse data in to the new array
        std::memcpy(pNewShipArray, shipArray, (sizeof(ship) * (shipCount - 1)));

        // delete previuse array
        delete[] shipArray;

        // now you can use shipArray
        shipArray = pNewShipArray;

    }
    // add new ship in to your array
    shipArray[shipCount - 1] = new_ship; // be carefull!! if you have pointers in your ship class you most handle them too.
}
```

Comment: When you answered a question please try to add some explanations before the code.